# Percentage of array between values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Im searching for an easy way to find which percentage of the data is within certain intervals using python.

Consider an array X of float values. I'd like to do something similar to quantiles:

```
X.quantile(np.linspace(0,1,11))
```

But instead, I'd like to know which percentage of values are within -10 and 10, for example.

```
X.method([-10,10])
```

I know I can do that with `scipy.stats.percentileofscore` doing

```
percentileofscore(X,10) - percentileofscore(X,-10)
```

I was wondering whether there's a simpler, implemented solution so I could do instead

```
X.method([a,b,c])
```

Which would give me the percentage of values between the `min(X)` and `a`, `a` and `b`,  `b` and `c`, and finally between `c` and `max(X)`

Comment: No, there isn't a pre-coded solution for this.  The one you posted is exactly how it's done.  If you need it often, just wrap it up in a function.

Comment: Are you looking for a predefined method or are you willing to write one yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you guys know I found a very simple solution to this using `value_counts` and `np.inf`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 100, 200))
values.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False, bins=[-np.inf, 10, 20, np.inf])
```

`normalize=True` returns percentages, setting it to False give the count

`sort=False` will return in the order of the bins, setting it to True will sort in descending values of the counts

`bins` define the interval points

This returns

```
(-inf, 10.0]    0.1
(10.0, 20.0]    0.1
(20.0, inf]     0.8
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution is to use `np.histogram`:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(20)
values = [5, 13]  # these are your a and b
freq = np.histogram(X, bins=[-np.inf] + values + [np.inf])[0]/X.size
print(freq)
>> array([0.25, 0.4 , 0.35])
```

Answer (score 5):

## Basic Numpy and Pandas solutions

There's no completely prepackaged method (in Numpy), but there's lots of one liners. Here's how to do it using comparison and logical ops (**Edit** tip of the hat to Paul Panzer for suggesting the use of `np.count_nonzero`):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.linspace(-15,15,1000)
np.count_nonzero((arr > -10) & (arr < 10))/arr.size
```

Output:

```
0.666
```

If you're willing to use Pandas, the [`pandas.Series.between` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas-series-between) gets you a little closer to the complete package you want:

```
import pandas as pd

sr = pd.Series(np.linspace(-15,15,1000))
np.count_nonzero(sr.between(-10,10))/sr.size
```

Output:

```
0.666
```

## Pitfalls

Every interval analysis method involves an explicit or implicit definition of the interval that you're considering. Is the interval closed (ie inclusive of the extreme values) on both ends, like `[-10, 10]`? Or is it half-open (ie excludes the extreme value on one end), like `[-10, 10)`? And so forth.

This tends not to be an issue when dealing with arrays of `float` values taken from data (since it's unlikely any of the data falls exactly on the extremes), but can cause serious problems when working with arrays of `int`. For example, the two methods I listed above can give different results if the array includes the boundary values of the interval:

```
arr = np.arange(-15,16)
print(np.count_nonzero((arr > -10) & (arr < 10))/arr.size)
print(np.count_nonzero(pd.Series(arr).between(-10,10))/arr.size)
```

Output:

```
0.6129032258064516
0.6774193548387096
```

The `pd.Series.between` method defaults to to a closed interval on both ends, so to match it in Numpy you'd have to use the inclusive comparison operators:

```
arr = np.arange(-15,16)
print(np.count_nonzero((arr >= -10) & (arr <= 10))/arr.size)
print(np.count_nonzero(pd.Series(arr).between(-10,10))/arr.size)
```

Output:

```
0.6774193548387096
0.6774193548387096
```

All of this to say: when you pick a method for this kind of interval analysis, be aware of it's boundary conventions, and use a consistent convention across all your related analyses.

## Other solutions

If you assume the data is sorted (or if you sort it yourself), you can use `np.searchsorted`:

```
arr = np.random.uniform(-15,15,100)
arr.sort()
np.diff(arr.searchsorted([-10, 10]))[0]/arr.size
```

Output:

```
0.65
```

Comment: I wouldn't even include the method that requires sorted data.  Even if the data is sorted, it's much slower than the other methods.  If the data is *not* sorted, it just introduces unneeded time complexity, O(n) vs O(nlogn)

Comment: `searchsorted` isn't what bounds the time complexity of that solution.

Comment: "`searchsorted` isn't what bounds..." you mean in the unsorted case, right? In the sorted case, at least theoretically it should be `O(log(n))`. If not, can you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

***Setup***

```
a = np.linspace(-15,15,1000)
```

---

No builtin method exists, but quite simple to define your own using `np.count_nonzero` and `size`.  In general:

```
c = (a > -10) & (a < 10)
np.count_nonzero(c) / a.size
```

You can wrap this in a function for convenience and to allow for cases where you want closed intervals:

```
def percent_between(a, lower, upper, closed_left=False, closed_right=False):
    """
    Finds the percentage of values between a range for a numpy array

    Parameters
    ----------
    a: np.ndarray
      numpy array to calculate percentage
    lower: int, float
      lower bound
    upper: int, float
      upper bound
    closed_left:
      closed left bound ( > vs >= )
    closed_right:
      closed right bound ( < vs <= )
    """
    l = np.greater if not closed_left else np.greater_equal
    r = np.less if not closed_right else np.less_equal

    c = l(a, lower) & r(a, upper)
    return np.count_nonzero(c) / a.size
```

```
percent_between(a, -10, 10)
```

```
0.666
```

Comment: @tel `np.count_nonzero` is what you want to use. And yes, it is quite a bit faster.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Neat. I updated my answer to use `count_nonzero`. At first I was a little confused since it looks like [`count_nonzero(a)` just calls `a.sum()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L430), but then I realized that wasn't [the default execution path](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L420).